# Meteor-angular2 with simpleschema

Tags: angular, meteor, simple-schema

I'm using meteor and angular2 in application. How to add simple schema meteor package and integrate it with typescript ?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Simple schema meteor package but not working properly with typescript.

Comment: can you please update what you tried will be a good starting point for us

Comment: @RahulSingh I want to add ORM for db. I've used mongoose in nodeJS. But what is alternative of mongoose in meteor-angular2.